Diagnose bash autocomplete issues
I have one binary on my system, fio installed via package manager which doesn't autocomplete files with tab once you've typed fio . I guess this means something must over overridding the autocomplete behavior but I don't even know how to begin diagnosing it.

I would debug it like this:

Run complete -p | grep 'fio' and see if something fio is related
On my machine I got complete -F _fio fio, that means fio is completing stuff with the _fio function (noted by the -F flag)
Look for the _fio function inside /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ with grep -R '_fio' or other completion directories if configured

If everything is there, then maybe fio doesn't have a correct completion?^^

Thanks, step 1 already worked: complete -F _service /etc/init.d/fi so it's using the _service completion function which expects fio to be a service (which it is in addition to the usual CLI thing as it turns out when installed as an ubuntu package, which is odd). So this _service function doesn't return appropriate completions for CLI use.
